# Clarify what is asked for in java Exceptions assignment

Tags: java, exception

The requirements of the following java assignment are unclear to me. Does anyone understand what is needed?

> **Assignment:** In the previous assignment, you implemented a stack and a list that both inherited from the abstract class `ArrayIntCollection`. In this next task you are supposed to extend that implementation by making it throw exceptions. If you try to perform operations that are not allowed (for example, if you try to call pop or peek on an empty stack or try to remove an element from a non existing position) you shall create and use the exception class `CollectionException` of the type UncheckedException. Also write a test program `ExceptionMain.java` that generates and catches exceptions from your modified methods.

The way I understand it, I need to create an exception class called `CollectionException`. This class needs to extend `UncheckedException`. (This part is not working, as I cannot find a class called `UncheckedException`).

Also, it is apparent whether I am to use `try\catch` or `throw` for this task?

Thanks to all!

Comment: please google "unchecked exception", it might answer many of your questions.

Comment: You throw Exceptions form your class when you detect an invalid method call. You can use try/catch in a test class to test if it works correctly. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I find it surprising that people obviously have professors that do not answer questions about homework assignments. You did ask him this question, didn't you? A professor should welcome such questions, because they help him to make his assignments less ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...by make it throw exceptions...

will mean, yes, you have to use `throw`.

> Also write a test program ExceptionMain.java that generates and catches exceptions from your modified methods.

At least here you will have to use `try...catch`.

Regarding "UncheckedException": Either there is a class of this name (perhaps in another package). Then you can ask your teacher where it is. Otherwise you can extend from `java.lang.RuntimeException` (which is an unchecked exception) and ask you teacher if that's OK.